# How change drawer slide with if (login account firebase) in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two drawer slide (one for register and login -- the second for profile and setting)
I want click on menu show menu1 if not signIn account and show menu2 when singIn account

I done this code but not working
what is solution for this problem
...........................................................................................

```
class PageMain extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = "HOMESCREEN";
  final FirebaseUser user;

  const PageMain({Key key, this.user}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PageMainState createState() => _PageMainState();
}

class _PageMainState extends State<PageMain> {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  Future<void> _handleDrawer()async{
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
      var current_user = await _auth.currentUser();
      if (current_user != null) {
        return Menu();
      } else {
        return Menu2();
      }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      endDrawer: new Drawer(
        child: _handleDrawer(),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFa49cee),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, left: 10.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 125.0,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.info),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        onPressed: () {
                          _scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
                          _handleDrawer();
                        
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 35.0,
          ),
          
    );
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner:
    false;
  }
}

class Menu extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
            child: Text(
              'Side menu',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green,
                image: DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/shaar.jpg'))),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.input,
                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl, color: Colors.red),
            title: Text('welcome',
                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18.0)),
            onTap: () => {},
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.email),
            title: Text('login',
                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18.0)),
            onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Login.id)},
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.add),
            title: Text('register',
                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18.0)),
            onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Registration.id)},
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.insert_emoticon),
            title: Text('info',
                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18.0)),
            onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pop()},
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Menu2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
            child: Text(
              'Side menu',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green,
                image: DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/shaar.jpg'))),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.input),
            title: Text('welcom', textDirection: TextDirection.rtl),
            onTap: () => {},
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.verified_user),
            title: Text('Profile'),
            onTap: () => {},
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
            title: Text('Settings'),
            onTap: () => {},
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
            title: Text('Logout'),
            onTap: () => {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think _handleDrawer() can return Future. Instead, try using a FutureBuilder. Show not SignedIn widget as default and wait for the future to check if User has signed in and rebuild accordingly.

Your endDrawer should be like so:

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: _auth.currentUser(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot) {
            
            if(snapshot.data != null) {
                return Menu();
            } else {
                return Menu2();
            }
            
        },
)
```

Comment: Done, use this widget instead of _handleDrawer().